# how can I sum values in a dictionary based on just one element of the tuple in the keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary with tuples as the keys that looks like the following:

```
myDict = {('A','A'):0,
        ('A','B'):3,
        ('A','C'):2,
        ('A','D'):5,
        ('B','A'):10,
        ('B','B'):13,
        ('B','C'):14,
        ('B','D'):12}
```

How can I sum all of the values where the first element in the tuple is `'B'` such that the result is `49`?

Comment: If you commonly need to do this sort of thing with the data, consider restructuring it as a dict of dicts - `{'A': {'A': 0, 'B': 3, 'C': 2, 'D': 5}, 'B': {'A': 10, 'B': 13, 'C': 14, 'D': 12}}`. That way you'll only need to iterate over the relevant keys to get the sum, instead of searching for them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sum()` on dictionary values where first item of tuple is 'B'

(Edited as per @rafaelc): Cleaner to not use the ternary operator here

```
sum(val for key, val in dict.items() if key[0] == 'B')
```

Instead of original:

```
 sum(val if key[0] == 'B' else 0 for key, val in dict.items())
```

Also, refrain from calling your dictionary as `dict`

Comment: Maybe `sum(val for key, val in dict_.items() if key[0] == 'B')` ? ;]

Comment: Also possible without indexing: `sum(val for (key, _), v in myDict.items() if key == 'B')`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use reserved words as variable names. Don't name your dictionary as `dict`.

```
data = {
    ('A','A'): 0,
    ('A','B'): 3,
    ('A','C'): 2,
    ('A','D'): 5,
    ('B','A'): 10,
    ('B','B'): 13,
    ('B','C'): 14,
    ('B','D'): 12
}

s = sum(
    value
    for key, value in data.items()
    if key[0] == 'B'
)
print(s)

s = sum(
    map(
        lambda itemf: itemf[1], 
        filter(
            lambda item: item[0][0] == 'B',
            data.items()
        )
    )
)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
49
49
```

Comment: Ah, someone else formats complex expressions the same way I do :)