# Tuple-key dictionary in python: Accessing a whole block of entries

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am looking for an efficient python method to utilise a hash table that has two keys:
E.g.:

```
(1,5) --> {a}
(2,3) --> {b,c}
(2,4) --> {d}
```

Further I need to be able to retrieve whole blocks of entries, for example all entries that have "2" at the 0-th position (here: (2,3) as well as (2,4)).
In another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58405269/how-can-i-sum-values-in-a-dictionary-based-on-just-one-element-of-the-tuple-in-t/69233502#69233502) it was suggested to use list comprehension, i.e.:

```
sum(val for key, val in dict.items() if key[0] == 'B')
```

I learned that dictionaries are (probably?) the most efficient way to retrieve a value from an object of key:value-pairs. However, calling only an incomplete tuple-key is a bit different than querying the whole key where I either get a value or nothing. I want to ask if python can still return the values in a time proportional to the number of key:value-pairs that match? Or alternatively, is the tuple-dictionary (plus list comprehension) better than using pandas.df.groupby() (but that would occupy a bit much memory space)?

Comment: Could you use a dictionary of dictionaries? So you'd get `{1: {5: {a}}, 2: {3: {b, c}, 4: {d}}}`, then you can get a "block" in O(1) too (rather than the O(n) scan of all keys you're currently doing).

Comment: "However, calling only an incomplete tuple-key is a bit different than querying the whole key where I either get a value or nothing. " It's not just a bit different. This changes the lookup from constant time to linear time (proportional to the total length of the dictionary). I think jonsharpe has a good suggestion.

Comment: I was reluctant to use a dictionary of dictionaries. But after you answered that lookup is becoming linear time, and also I noted that it suits my code better than I initially thought, I adopted the dictionary of dictionary method.   Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "standard" way would be something like

```
d = {(randint(1,10),i):"something" for i,x in enumerate(range(200))}

def byfilter(n,d):
    return list(filter(lambda x:x==n, d.keys()))

byfilter(5,d) ##returns a list of tuples where x[0] == 5
```

Although in similar situations I often used `next()` to iterate manually, when I didn't need the full list.

However there may be some use cases where we can optimize that. Suppose you need to do a couple or more accesses by key first element, and you know the dict keys are not changing meanwhile. Then you can extract the keys in a list and sort it, and make use of some `itertools` functions, namely `dropwhile()` and `takewhile()`:

```
ls = [x for x in d.keys()]
ls.sort() ##I do not know why but this seems faster than ls=sorted(d.keys())

def bysorted(n,ls):
    return list(takewhile(lambda x: x[0]==n, dropwhile(lambda x: x[0]!=n, ls)))
bysorted(5,ls) ##returns the same list as above
```

This can be up to 10x faster in the best case (`i=1` in my example) and more or less take the same time in the worst case (`i=10`) because we are trimming the number of iterations needed.

Of course you can do the same for accessing keys by `x[1]`, you just need to add a `key` parameter to the `sort()` call